# Clarifying what 'only a single prototype mutation is permitted in an object literal' means

Tags: javascript

This MDN [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) says

> Only a single prototype mutation is permitted in an object literal. Multiple prototype mutations are a syntax error.

Would someone be able to give me an explanation of this with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{a: 'b', a: 'c'}
```

This is valid syntax, even though repeating the key `a` makes no sense and the resulting object is just `{a: 'c'}`.

```
{__proto__: {}, __proto__: {}}
```

This is an actual syntax error, even though you'd think it's the same thing as above. `__proto__` is treated special in this way and only allowed once.